# Button isn't responsive

Tags: javascript, html, web

I created a button but it doesn't work, it is supposed to trigger a function I have defined in javascript, but it doesn't work.

Javascript
The start game function is supposed to be triggered as soon as the user clicks the button, but the button is unresponsive and nothing happenes.

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')



startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
 currentQuestionIndex++
 setNextQuestion()
})
function startGame() {
 startButton.classList.add('hide')
 shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
 currentQuestionIndex = 0
 questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
 setNextQuestion(shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex)
 setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}   



 function showQuestion(question) {
    questionElement.innerText = question.question
    question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
       button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    })
    }

   function resetState() {
     clearStatusClass(document.body)
     nextButton.classList.add('hide')
     while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
     answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
   } 
   }

   function selectAnswer(e) {
       const  selectedButton = e.target
       const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
       setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
       Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(child => {
       setStatusClass(child, child.dataset.correct)
       Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
       setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
    })
    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    } 
    else { 
      startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
      startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
    }

    ,function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
       clearStatusClass(element)
       if (correct) {
        element.classList.add('correct')
       } 
       else {
        element.classList.add('wrong')
        }
       }

     ,function clearStatusClass(element) {
         element.classList.remove('wrong')
         element.classList.remove('correct')
         element.classList.remove('wrong')
       }

       const questions = [
        {
         question: 'e',
         answers: [
           { text: 'e', correct: true },
           { text: 'e', correct: false }
         ]
        },
        {
          question: '7',
          answers: [
           { text: 'e', correct: true },
           { text: 'e', correct: true },
           { text: 'e', correct: true },
           { text: 'e', correct: true }
         ]
       },
```

HTML

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     
     <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href ="actualApp.css">
       <script defer src="actualApp.js"></script>
       <title>Quiz App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
              <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
              <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
              <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
              <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="controls">
       <button  onclick = "startGame()" id="start-btn" class="btn btn-start">Start</button>
       <button id="next-btn" class="btn btn-next hide">Next</button>  
       </div>
       </div>
       </body>  
     </html>
```

The start button has an onclick attribute that is supposed to trigger the startGame function, but it doesn't.

Comment: Have you checked the console for the error messages? Also, you shouldn't need the inline click listener, there's a listener added in the JS (`startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)`).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just checked. It says `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (126:0)` and `','expected. ` I don't really understand the error. The only character on line 126 is a curly bracket that I used to close the "questions" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to look in your console for any bugs I hope this helps but  I put this code into playcode.io and it threw back this in the console.

```
error: /script.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (86:7)

  84 |        }
  85 |
> 86 |        const questions = [
     |        ^
  87 |         {
  88 |          question: 'e',
  89 |          answers: [
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I solved this error but then 2 more appeared. The console hit me with `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (126:0)` and `',' expected.` I have no idea what this means because the only code that is on that line is a singular curly bracket I used to close the "questions" variable

Comment: can you show me the full question variable in JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, but do you have a discord or anything I can contact you with, it isn't allowing me post the code here, it is too long.